# Attribute Routing gives 404 for api/delete/1

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I am doing a SPA with web api as the backend and AngularJS as the SPA.

I am using attribute routing in WebApi2. The problem is when I do any http request that matches the following skeleton, it throws me a 404 NOT Found.

Request: `http://localhost:63915/api/cab/delete/2`

Request:
[image: Request]

[image]

Error:[image]

WebApiConfig Code:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        
    }
}
```

RouteDeclaration:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/driver")]
public class DriverController : ApiController
{
    [POST("new")]
    public bool NewDriver(DriverModel driver)
    {
        return new DatabaseService().CreateNewDriver(driver);
    }

    [GET("all")]
    public List<DriverModel> GetAllDrivers()
    {
        return new DatabaseService().GetDriverList();
    }

    [DELETE("delete/{id}")]
    public bool Delete(int id)
    {
        return new DatabaseService().DeleteDriver(id);
    }
}
```

If I do something like `api/driver/delete?id=2` and change the route to `[DELETE("delete")]` it works.

Is everything all right with my config ?

I think the problem might be with my config only. Please tell me what I am missing to make the route work.

Comment: api/driver/delete/1 does not match "api/{controller}/{id}"; neither does api/cab/delete/2 ...?

Comment: @MarcGravell, the routeprefix should take care of that, shouldn't it?

Comment: What changes do I have to make to the config in order to make this route work ? @Marc Gravell

Comment: @AD.Net as I understand it, no; because a: the code doesn't use `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`, and b: I thought the route-prefix only applied to those actions decorated with `[Route(...)]`

Comment: @MarcGravell, the 2nd point is a good catch. I assumed he did the 1st, by default it's usually there.

Comment: @MarcGravell, If the `RoutePrefix` is only applied to actions decorated with `[Route()]`, then why are all my other routes working absolutely fine ?

Comment: @Ven do the ones that work all match "api/{controller}/{id}" ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes they do. And the others that don't work don't have a specified template, so I added the Route as stated in the below answer. And then everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another route to the WebApiConfig and it works!

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ComplexApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Please see Marc Gravell's comments, I think that's the problem.